# UITableViewController + Autolayout + estimaterowheight scroll up issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I’m dealing with a strange issue on a UITableViewController when scrolls up. (see video below)

The UITableViewCell (a custom one) is height variable and use Autolayout and the new iOS8 estimateRowHeight and the rowHeight is set in the viewDidLoad to UITableViewAutomaticDimension. The table has 1000 rows and uses NSFetchedResultsController
I have tried example from Apple, from StackOverflow, and works well with 50 or 100 cells, but no more.
I also tried with constrains in storyboard and constrains in code
Any suggestions are welcome.

Video:
http://youtu.be/0Jna4rXIRAM

UITableViewController code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 70, 0);
    self.myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0f;
    [self.myTableView registerClass:[ShotTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ShotTableViewCell *cell = (ShotTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPAth:indexPath];

    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    return cell;
}

-(void)configureCell:(ShotTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPAth:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Shot *shot = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureBasicCellWithShot:shot andRow:indexPath.row];


    [cell addTarget:self action:@selector(goProfile:)];
}

-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    //GET THE DATA
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[ShotManager singleton] getShotsForTimeLine];
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.myTableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.myTableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:{
            self.tableTypeOfChange = k_Insert;
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:{
            self.tableTypeOfChange = k_Delete;
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:{
            self.tableTypeOfChange = k_Update;
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:{
            self.tableTypeOfChange = k_Move;
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.myTableView endUpdates];
}
```

ShotTableViewCell code:

```
-(void)configureBasicCellWithShot:(Shot *)shot andRow:(NSInteger)row {

    self.txvText.attributedText = [TimeLineUtilities filterLinkWithContent:shot.comment];

    self.lblName.text = shot.user.userName;

    self.imgPhoto = [DownloadImage downloadImageForTimeLineWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:shot.user.photo] andUIimageView:self.imgPhoto andText:[shot.user.name substringToIndex:1]];

    self.lblDate.text = [TimeLineUtilities getDateShot:shot.csys_birth];
    self.btnPhoto.tag = row;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Make sure the contentView does a layout pass here so that its subviews have their frames set, which we
    // need to use to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth below.
    [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

    // Set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the mutli-line bodyLabel based on the evaluated width of the label's frame,
    // as this will allow the text to wrap correctly, and as a result allow the label to take on the correct height.

   self.txvText.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.txvText.frame)
}
```

Comment: The video is private.

Comment: @Christian: I'm facing same issue. Would you please share its solution here.